# Strange issue with IE converting certain url params into html entities

Tags: internet-explorer, url, encoding

I have a url that contains these parameters:

```
&lt_ts1=blah&gt_ts1=blah
```

Internet Explorer takes it upon itself to change it to this (regardless of a lack of semi-colons):

```
<_ts1=blah>_ts1=blah
```

The url string is generated in PHP. Is there any way of protecting the url in IE without changing the parameter names (worst case scenario)?

Ta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always put the ampersand as an entity like so:

```
&amp;lt_ts1=blah&amp;gt_ts1=blah
```

I guess that IE treat &lt as a < sign, even if there is no ; at the end. (&lt being the < entity)

Comment: Hmm, that DID work in IE! Unfortunately it now mucks up Firefox. Is there something clever I can do to detect the browser version? I'm using jQuery within this document...

Comment: Could you try replacing &amp; with %26? Which is the hex number for &. Might work in both :)