# GWT Window.open in IE 11 misinterprets query parameter &deg=123

Tags: internet-explorer, url, gwt, encoding

In a `GWT` application I try to open a `Window` passing a `url` which contains query parameters. It happens that one parameter is named: `deg_test`, so the formated url is something like: `http://localhost:8888/mymodule/search?param1=value1&param2=value2&deg_test=123`.

In `Chrome` and `Firefox` the window opens as expected, however in `IE 11` the `&deg_` part is misinterpreted to `&deg;` and it is converted to the degree symbol (º) and breaks the url!

Sample code:

```
String query = "?param1=value1&param2=value2&deg_test=123";
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open("http://localhost:8888/mymodule/search"
                    + URL.encode(query), "_blank", "resizable=yes"
```

IE window URL: `http://localhost:8888/mymodule/search?param1=value1&param2=value2°_test=123`

If I use the `URL.encodeQueryString` method instead of the `URL.encode` both `?` and `&` will be encoded and server will complain with `404`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's not GWT problem just general issue with IE. It will convert anything that looks like an entity (without `;` at the end), for example:
`&deg`, `&lt`, `&gt` to `°`, `<`, `>` respectively. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401587/strange-issue-with-ie-converting-certain-url-params-into-html-entities).

As a quick workaround I suggest you to put the `deg_test` param at the beginning of the query. This way you will not get `&deg` fragment but `?deg` instead.

```
?deg_test=123&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the proposed workaround will work, however the truth is that in the real application I have multiple "deg_..." parameters that are arbitrarily added as query parameters so this eventually does not solve my problem. I will upvote your answer but I am afraid I cannot accept it as solution.

Comment: Actually your link to the other question led me to solve my problem. Many thanks, marking this as the correct answer!